# viewdidload executed as soon as instantiateviewcontroller is called

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, viewdidload

I am loading `UIViewcontroller` from storyboard using `instantiateviewcontroller` method of `UIStoryboard`. As soon as this method is executed, `viewDidLoad()` method is called, even before `initWithCoder`. This behaviour is different and contradicts lazy loading.

Now, the problem is how to set properties on `UIViewcontroller` so that I can use them in `viewDidLoad` method ?

Comment: My thoughts is that your view controller was instantiated in some other manner before "instantiateviewcontroller" call.

Comment: Thanks for replying but No, I am not loading viewcontroller anywhere else. Also, I am not calling viewcontroller.view anywhere in my code

Comment: Double check storyboard for segues to the view controller.

Comment: No segues too, thats why I used intantiateViewController method

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: I'd be likely to put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and look at the stack trace to see how the app got there.

Comment: This is the stack trace
`[NewsViewController viewDidLoad] 
[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:][UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:][PagerViewController viewDidLoad]`

Comment: Since that doesn't happen if I try it in a very simple case, there must be something a bit unusual about the configuration of `NewsViewController`.  (I'm assuming that if you create a new project with two basic view controllers and instantiate the second from the `viewDidLoad` of the first, you don't see the same problem either.)

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks buddy, I connected tableview as view  as well as tableview property of the viewcontroller. Hence it was calling viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not correctly understand you initial question.
But i think you want something like this

```
-(void) loadNewVC {
    SampleViewController *sample = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sample"];
    NSData *birthData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iglesiasSite.com"]];
    sample.someName = @"Enrique Iglesias";
    sample.someData = birthData;

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:sample];
}
```

in header of SampleViewController.h class

```
@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *someData;
@end
```

SampleViewController.m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self processData: self.someData andName: someName];
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i am doing, but just after first line `SampleViewController *sample = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sample"];` is executed, viewDidLoad is called inside which you will find that self.someData and self.someName are nil as they are yet to be set by their setters.

Comment: @NishitGoenka I think you should provide a sample project, upload it to github and let people see the whole picture here. Otherwise I can't see why Mr.Fingers' answer is incorrect to your question in any way.

Comment: I was doing the exact same thing as Mr. Fingers wrote here. Problem was in the storyboard, I connected UITableview as both tableview outlet and view outlet and deleted UIView object, hence the UITableview was loading at the time of instantiation as it was the view outlet of the viewcontroller, and hence viewDidLoad() was getting called